# Problems with long table and formatting problems

Tags: tables

I have made this table and I would like to know how to merge the entries 'Set flow rate','Q_{set}' and 'Experimental parameters' into one cell so that I don't repeat it.

[image]
[image]

Secondly, how do I keep the numbers aligned in the columns 'Batch 1' and 'Batch 2' while cutting all the extra space I have on the left (I am trying not to let the table exceed the page space)?

[image]

Then how can I increase the height of the rows so then the units in the last column are not cut off?

[image]

I would also like to know how to center the numbers or words in the cell, since at the moment they occupy only the upper part of each cell.

[image]

Lastly, I would like to make these three tables a big table that breaks when the page is full. I tried to implement the package longtable without succeeding.

```
\documentclass[table]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mEq}{mEq}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{MyWhite}{rgb}{0.98,0.96,1}
\definecolor{LightMauve}{rgb}{0.86,0.82,1}


%% page settings

%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
% needed for page border 
% settings (indicazioni sup, inf, sx = 3 cm e dx = 2.5 cm; 
% interlinea 1.5 (ok), didascalia figure e tabelle times new roman 10
% margini che avevo : 2 sopra e sotto, 2.5 dx e sx
\parindent=0cm % for space of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hyphenless justification (tries to)
\hyphenation{} 
%\hyphenpenalty=10000 -> a capo posso andare se lo tolgo
%\exhyphenpenalty=10000 -> togliendo questo codice matlab va a capo e anche alcune parole nel testo
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % needed for head and foot options
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]

  \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|S[table-column-width=4cm]|S[table-column-width=4cm]| S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}

    Initial instant of time & \ch{t_0} & 0 & 0 & \si{\s} \\ 
    Initial length & \ch{l_0} & 0 & 0 & \si{\m} \\
    Set flow rate & \ch{Q_{set}} & 11.5 & 4.78 & $\dfrac{ml}{min}$ \\
    Set flow rate & \ch{Q_{set}} & 1.9167E-7 & 7.9667E-8 & $\dfrac{m^3}{s}$ \\
    Velocity of reaction & \ch{K_{ads}} & 0.5 & 0.027 &$\dfrac{m^3}{mol \cdot s}$  \\
    Diffusion coefficient of urea in \ch{H_2O} & \ch{D_L} & 1.38E-9 & 1.38E-9 & $\dfrac{m^2}{s}$ \\
     Concentration of the inlet solution & \ch{C_{in}} & 5.07 & 4.9 &$\dfrac{mol}{m^3}$ \\
      Density of the sorbent & $ \rho_s $ & 9.8E4 & 9.8E4 & $\dfrac{g}{m^3}$ \\
       Porosity of the sorbent & $ \epsilon_s $ & 0.9414 & 0.94 &  {-}  \\
        Height of the swelling of the sorbent & $ h_s $ & 0.15 & 0.1667 & $\%$\\
        Length of the sorbent & $ l_s $ & 0.0184 & 0.0184 & \si{m} \\
        Final set length of the sorbent & $ l_{f_{set}} $ & 0.0212 & 0.0215 & \si{m} \\
       Diameter of the sorbent  & $d_s$ & 0.0127 & 0.0127 & \si{m} \\
       Diameter of the reference sorbent & $ d_{{s}_{ref}} $ & 0.0127 & 0.0127 & \si{m} \\
        Ratio between $d_s$ and $d_{{s}_{ref}}$  & x & 1 & 1 & {-} \\
        Final length of the sorbent & $l_f$ & 0.0212 & 0.0215 & \si{m} \\

    \hhline{-||----}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]

  \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|S[table-column-width=4cm]|S[table-column-width=4cm]| S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}

           Molar mass of urea & $ M_{urea} $ & 60.06 & 60.06 & $\dfrac{g}{mol}$ \\
        Mass of urea at the inlet & $m_{{urea}_{in}}$ & 10.5054 & 4.2202 & \si{mg} \\
        Step size & $ D_z $ & 2.5E-4 & 2.5E-4 & \si{m} \\
        Average velocity of the solution in the sorbent  & $\overline{v}$ & 0.0016 & 6.6904E-4 &$\dfrac{m}{s}$ \\
        Crossing time & $t_{cross}$ & 0.2194 & 0.5348 & \si{min} \\
Set duration of the simulation & $\Delta t_{sim}$ & 180 & 180 & \si{s} \\
Simulation time based on sorbent length & $t_{sim}$ & 193.1656 & 212.0867 & \si{s} \\
Langmuir constant & $k_L$ & 0.0145 & 0.0145 & $\dfrac{m^3}{mol}$ \\
Maximum adsorbtion capacity & $Q_{max}$ & 133.34 & 133.34 & $\dfrac{mg_{urea}}{g_{sorbent}}$ \\ 
Value of the second order kinetic model & $k_2$ & 0.115 & 0.115 & $\dfrac{g_{sorbent}}{mg_{urea} \cdot min}$ \\
Number of space intervals & $N_{int_z}$ & 84 & 85 & {-} \\
Contact time between sorbent and fluid & $t_{contact}$ & 0.0026 & 0.0063 & \si{min} \\
$C_{initial}$ of urea in the sorbent & $C_0$ & 0 & 0 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Experimental parameter & $par_1$ & 0.8184 & 0.8184 & {-} \\
Experimental parameter & $par_2$ & 0.008 & 0.008 & {-} \\
Experimental parameter & $par_3$ & 4.3 & 4.3 & {-} \\
Experimental parameter & $par_4$ & 4.76 & 4.76 & {-} \\
$C_{eq}$ of urea in the solution & $C_{eq}$ & 4.1493 & 4.0102 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Concentration of urea in the sorbent & $csp$ & 217.5711 & 217.5711 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Time step & $D_t$ & 0.0771 & 0.1837 & $s$ \\
Maximum time step & $D_{t_{max}}$ & 0.1542 & 0.3674 & $s$ \\
Number of time intervals & $N_{int_t}$ & 2506 & 1154 & {-} \\
Peclet number & Pe & 2.4644E4 & 1.0408E4 & {-} \\
Damk{\"o}hler number & Dam & 3.5296E7 & 1.9617E6 & {-} \\

    \hhline{-||----}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb2}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]

  \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|S[table-column-width=4cm]|S[table-column-width=4cm]| S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}

Diffusion constant & $K_{diff}$ & 0.0017 & 0.0041 & {-} \\
Convection constant & $K_{conv}$ & 0.4955 & 0.4916 & {-} \\
Beta    & $\beta$ & 42.9134 & 44.4023 & $\dfrac{m^3_{solution}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Alpha & $\alpha$ & 1 & 1 & {-} \\
Adsorption capacity of the sorbent & $Q_e$ & 7.5671 & 7.3273 & $\dfrac{mg_{urea}}{g_{sorbent}}$ \\
Adsorption capacity over $ t_{contact}$ & $Q_t$ & 5.5766 & 5.4856 & $\dfrac{mg_{urea}}{g_{sorbent}}$ \\
$C_{max}$ of urea in the sorbent (over $t_{contact}$) & $csp_{ist}$ & 0.0270 & 0.0585 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Cumulative quantity of urea adsorbed & $w_{urea,ads}$ & 0.7184 & 0.2113 & $mg$ \\
Percentage of urea adsorbed & $\%_{urea,ads}$ & 6.8379 & 5.0078 & $\%$ \\
Additional duration to reach saturation & $\Delta t_{sat}$ & 50 & 50 & $s$ \\
Variation of concentration & $\Delta c$ & 2.9136 & 2.6270 & $\dfrac{mol}{m^3}$ \\
Saturation of the sponge & $sat$ & 87.3763 & 23.3251 & $\%$ \\

    \hhline{-||----}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the partial answer of user @MichaelPalmer let us have a look to the second part of answer, the usage of `longtable` and the too big space left of the numbers ...

Your code uses  `siunitx` to format the numbers and the space of the table columns (`S`).  Therefore you can add `table-format = +1.4e+4` to `\sisetup` to get one number before the dezimal point, 4 after it (+1.4) and for the exponent use 4 characters (e+4).  Now you can get a smaller width for a column with `S[table-column-width=3cm]`.

All this changes you will find in the following part of code:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]

% \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,table-format = +1.4e+4} % 1 integer,4 dezimal 4 exponent
%                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||%
                   >{\centering}p{1.5cm}|%
                   S[table-column-width=4cm]|%
                   S[table-column-width=3cm]|% <========================
                   S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
    \hhline{~----}
```

To be able to use environment `longtable` you can use the following code to start the longtable:

```
{ \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,table-format = +1.4e+4} % 1 integer,4 dezimal 4 exponent
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{MyWhite}{LightMauve}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||
                   >{\centering}p{1.5cm}|
                   S[table-column-width=4cm]| 
                   S[table-column-width=3cm]| % <=======================
                   S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the 
           simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb2}\\
  \toprule
\endfirsthead
  \toprule
\endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{to be continued ...} \\
  \midrule
\endfoot
  \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
```

and

```
\end{longtable}
}
```

to end it. See that the closing bracket is needed to close the group I started to have fontsize `small` and the `sisetup` only available for `longtable`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[table]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mEq}{mEq}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % <===============================================
\usepackage{longtable} % <==============================================
\definecolor{MyWhite}{rgb}{0.98,0.96,1}
\definecolor{LightMauve}{rgb}{0.86,0.82,1}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % <=====================================


%% page settings

\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\parindent=0cm % for space of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hyphenless justification (tries to)
\hyphenation{} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % needed for head and foot options
%\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]

% \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,table-format = +1.4e+4} % 1 integer,4 dezimal 4 exponent
%                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||%
                   >{\centering}p{1.5cm}|%
                   S[table-column-width=4cm]|%
                   S[table-column-width=3cm]|% <========================
                   S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}
Initial instant of time & \ch{t_0}      & 0         & 0         & \si{\s} \\ 
Initial length          & \ch{l_0}      & 0         & 0         & \si{\m} \\
Set flow rate           & \ch{Q_{set}}  & 11.5      & 4.78      & $\nicefrac{ml}{min}$ \\
"                       & \ch{Q_{set}}  & 1.9167E-7 & 7.9667E-8 & $\nicefrac{m^3}{s}$ \\
Velocity of reaction    & \ch{K_{ads}}  & 0.5       & 0.027     & $\nicefrac{m^3}{mol \cdot s}$ \\
Diffusion coefficient of 
  urea in \ch{H_2O}     & \ch{D_L}      & 1.38E-9   & 1.38E-9   & $\nicefrac{m^2}{s}$ \\
Concentration of the 
  inlet solution        & \ch{C_{in}}   & 5.07      & 4.9       & $\nicefrac{mol}{m^3}$ \\
Density of the sorbent  & $ \rho_s $    & 9.8E4     & 9.8E4     & $\nicefrac{g}{m^3}$ \\
Porosity of the sorbent & $\epsilon_s$  & 0.9414    & 0.94      &  {-}  \\
Height of the swelling 
  of the sorbent        & $ h_s $       & 0.15      & 0.1667    & $\%$\\
Length of the sorbent   & $ l_s $       & 0.0184    & 0.0184    & \si{m} \\
Final set length of the 
  sorbent               & $l_{f_{set}}$ & 0.0212    & 0.0215    & \si{m} \\
Diameter of the sorbent & $d_s$         & 0.0127    & 0.0127    & \si{m} \\
Diameter of the 
  reference sorbent     &$d_{{s}_{ref}}$& 0.0127    & 0.0127    & \si{m} \\
Ratio between $d_s$ and 
  $d_{{s}_{ref}}$       & x             & 1         & 1         & {-} \\
Final length of the 
  sorbent               & $l_f$         & 0.0212    & 0.0215    & \si{m} \\
    \hhline{-||----}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb1}
\end{table}

\clearpage
{ \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,table-format = +1.4e+4} % 1 integer,4 dezimal 4 exponent
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{MyWhite}{LightMauve}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||
                   >{\centering}p{1.5cm}|
                   S[table-column-width=4cm]| 
                   S[table-column-width=3cm]| % <=======================
                   S[table-column-width=2cm]|}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the 
           simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb2}\\
  \toprule
\endfirsthead
  \toprule
\endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{to be continued ...} \\
  \midrule
\endfoot
  \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}
Initial instant of time & \ch{t_0}      & 0         & 0         & \si{\s} \\ 
Initial length          & \ch{l_0}      & 0         & 0         & \si{\m} \\
Set flow rate           & \ch{Q_{set}}  & 11.5      & 4.78      & $\nicefrac{ml}{min}$ \\
"                       & \ch{Q_{set}}  & 1.9167E-7 & 7.9667E-8 & $\nicefrac{m^3}{s}$ \\
Velocity of reaction    & \ch{K_{ads}}  & 0.5       & 0.027     & $\nicefrac{m^3}{mol \cdot s}$ \\
Diffusion coefficient of 
  urea in \ch{H_2O}     & \ch{D_L}      & 1.38E-9   & 1.38E-9   & $\nicefrac{m^2}{s}$ \\
Concentration of the 
  inlet solution        & \ch{C_{in}}   & 5.07      & 4.9       & $\nicefrac{mol}{m^3}$ \\
Density of the sorbent  & $ \rho_s $    & 9.8E4     & 9.8E4     & $\nicefrac{g}{m^3}$ \\
Porosity of the sorbent & $\epsilon_s$  & 0.9414    & 0.94      &  {-}  \\
Height of the swelling 
  of the sorbent        & $ h_s $       & 0.15      & 0.1667    & $\%$\\
Length of the sorbent   & $ l_s $       & 0.0184    & 0.0184    & \si{m} \\
Final set length of the 
  sorbent               & $l_{f_{set}}$ & 0.0212    & 0.0215    & \si{m} \\
Diameter of the sorbent & $d_s$         & 0.0127    & 0.0127    & \si{m} \\
Diameter of the 
  reference sorbent     &$d_{{s}_{ref}}$& 0.0127    & 0.0127    & \si{m} \\
Ratio between $d_s$ and 
  $d_{{s}_{ref}}$       & x             & 1         & 1         & {-} \\
Final length of the 
  sorbent               & $l_f$         & 0.0212    & 0.0215    & \si{m} \\

Molar mass of urea & $ M_{urea} $ & 60.06 & 60.06 & $\nicefrac{g}{mol}$ \\
Mass of urea at the inlet & $m_{{urea}_{in}}$ & 10.5054 & 4.2202 & \si{mg} \\
Step size & $ D_z $ & 2.5E-4 & 2.5E-4 & \si{m} \\
Average velocity of the solution in the sorbent  & $\overline{v}$ & 0.0016 & 6.6904E-4 &$\dfrac{m}{s}$ \\
Crossing time & $t_{cross}$ & 0.2194 & 0.5348 & \si{min} \\
Set duration of the simulation & $\Delta t_{sim}$ & 180 & 180 & \si{s} \\
Simulation time based on sorbent length & $t_{sim}$ & 193.1656 & 212.0867 & \si{s} \\
Langmuir constant & $k_L$ & 0.0145 & 0.0145 & $\dfrac{m^3}{mol}$ \\
Maximum adsorbtion capacity & $Q_{max}$ & 133.34 & 133.34 & $\dfrac{mg_{urea}}{g_{sorbent}}$ \\ 
Value of the second order kinetic model & $k_2$ & 0.115 & 0.115 & $\nicefrac{g_{sorbent}}{mg_{urea} \cdot min}$ \\
Number of space intervals & $N_{int_z}$ & 84 & 85 & {-} \\
Contact time between sorbent and fluid & $t_{contact}$ & 0.0026 & 0.0063 & \si{min} \\
$C_{initial}$ of urea in the sorbent & $C_0$ & 0 & 0 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Experimental parameter & $par_1$ & 0.8184 & 0.8184 & {-} \\
"                      & $par_2$ & 0.008 & 0.008 & {-} \\
"                      & $par_3$ & 4.3 & 4.3 & {-} \\
"                      & $par_4$ & 4.76 & 4.76 & {-} \\
$C_{eq}$ of urea in the solution & $C_{eq}$ & 4.1493 & 4.0102 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Concentration of urea in the sorbent & $csp$ & 217.5711 & 217.5711 & $\dfrac{mol_{urea}}{m^3_{sorbent}}$ \\
Time step & $D_t$ & 0.0771 & 0.1837 & $s$ \\
Maximum time step & $D_{t_{max}}$ & 0.1542 & 0.3674 & $s$ \\
Number of time intervals & $N_{int_t}$ & 2506 & 1154 & {-} \\
    \hhline{-||----}
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

you get the results:

[image: first table]

for the first table and

[image: longtable]

for the start of the longtable ...

Please see that the column for `Batch2` is smaller (3cm) than the column for `batch1` (4cm).

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer only. I have replaced the column specifiers with `p`, and the `\dfrac` macros for the units with `\nicefrac` from package `nicefrac`, which reduces the height. I have removed the `\linespread` setting and instead increased `\arraystretch`, which increases the space between table rows, but not the interline distance within. I have commented out all table-related packages that are not used in the current version of the code.

Your request to merge table cells with identical contents doesn't mesh too well with the use of alternating row colors. If you want to keep the latter, I would suggest to just fill the repeating cells with something like `"`.

I haven't tried to fix the horizontal alignment within the cells. The docs of the `dcolumn` package aren't that straightforward, and I need to attend to my day job now.

```
\documentclass[table]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mEq}{mEq}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{cellspace}
%setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
%\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
%\usepackage{tabularx} 
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\definecolor{MyWhite}{rgb}{0.98,0.96,1}
\definecolor{LightMauve}{rgb}{0.86,0.82,1}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

%% page settings

%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry} 
% needed for page border 
% settings (indicazioni sup, inf, sx = 3 cm e dx = 2.5 cm; 
% interlinea 1.5 (ok), didascalia figure e tabelle times new roman 10
% margini che avevo : 2 sopra e sotto, 2.5 dx e sx
\parindent=0cm % for space of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hyphenless justification (tries to)
\hyphenation{} 
%\hyphenpenalty=10000 -> a capo posso andare se lo tolgo
%\exhyphenpenalty=10000 -> togliendo questo codice matlab va a capo e anche alcune parole nel testo
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % needed for head and foot options
%\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]

%  \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightMauve}{MyWhite}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{3.5cm}||>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}| p{2cm}|}
    \hhline{~----}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Symbol} & {Batch 1} & {Batch 2} & {Unit}  \\
    \hhline{-::====:}

    Initial instant of time & \ch{t_0} & 0 & 0 & \si{\s} \\ 
    Initial length & \ch{l_0} & 0 & 0 & \si{\m} \\
    Set flow rate & \ch{Q_{set}} & 11.5 & 4.78 & $\nicefrac{ml}{min}$ \\
    Set flow rate & \ch{Q_{set}} & 1.9167E-7 & 7.9667E-8 & $\nicefrac{m^3}{s}$ \\
    Velocity of reaction & \ch{K_{ads}} & 0.5 & 0.027 &$\nicefrac{m^3}{mol \cdot s}$  \\
    Diffusion coefficient of urea in \ch{H_2O} & \ch{D_L} & 1.38E-9 & 1.38E-9 & $\nicefrac{m^2}{s}$ \\
     Concentration of the inlet solution & \ch{C_{in}} & 5.07 & 4.9 &$\nicefrac{mol}{m^3}$ \\
      Density of the sorbent & $ \rho_s $ & 9.8E4 & 9.8E4 & $\nicefrac{g}{m^3}$ \\
       Porosity of the sorbent & $ \epsilon_s $ & 0.9414 & 0.94 &  {-}  \\
        Height of the swelling of the sorbent & $ h_s $ & 0.15 & 0.1667 & $\%$\\
        Length of the sorbent & $ l_s $ & 0.0184 & 0.0184 & \si{m} \\
        Final set length of the sorbent & $ l_{f_{set}} $ & 0.0212 & 0.0215 & \si{m} \\
       Diameter of the sorbent  & $d_s$ & 0.0127 & 0.0127 & \si{m} \\
       Diameter of the reference sorbent & $ d_{{s}_{ref}} $ & 0.0127 & 0.0127 & \si{m} \\
        Ratio between $d_s$ and $d_{{s}_{ref}}$  & x & 1 & 1 & {-} \\
        Final length of the sorbent & $l_f$ & 0.0212 & 0.0215 & \si{m} \\

    \hhline{-||----}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Boundary and inlet conditions and output values for the simulation of the adsorbtion phenomenon for batch 1 and 2.}
  \label{tableb1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]